# Symfony2 MongoDB Doctrine ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I just want to regenerate a new random Id for a document.
I didn't found the function `ObjectId()` (Mongodb) in doctrine.

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

First read about [Identifiers](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#basic-mapping-identifiers).

You will need to write your own generator or use one of existing (if they will match your case).

Example with custom setting of ID:

```
/** @Id(strategy="NONE", type="string") */
private $id;

public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

`NONE` - Do not generate any identifier. ID must be manually set.